# Trigger state change in model from another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

New to rails and learning how to use [state machines.](https://github.com/aasm/aasm) How would I make the fans of an actor, whose state is crying, change to the same crying state?

```
class Actor < ApplicationRecord
  include AASM

  has_many :fans 

  aasm do
    state :laughing, :initial => true
    state :crying

    event :cry do
      transitions :from => :laughing, :to => :crying
    end
    event :laugh do
      transitions :from => :crying, :to => :laughing
    end
  end
end  

class Fan < ApplicationRecord
  include AASM

  belongs_to :author 

  aasm do
    state :laughing, :initial => true
    state :crying

    event :cry do
      transitions :from => :laughing, :to => :crying
    end
    event :laugh do
      transitions :from => :crying, :to => :laughing
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [lifecycle callbacks](https://github.com/aasm/aasm#lifecycle) to trigger further methods on an actor:

```
class Actor < ApplicationRecord
  include AASM

  has_many :fans 

  aasm do
    state :laughing, :initial => true
    state :crying, :success => :fans_cry_too

    # ...
  end

  private

  def fans_cry_too
    fans.each(&:cry)
  end
end
```